Why don't Democrats let Representative Greene rename post offices, and how do they prevent her from doing so?
After 06:00 in CNN's April 19 18, 2024 MTG says GOP support is ‘growing’ to oust Speaker Johnson there are several quick clips of Democratic representatives suggesting they would not vote to vacate if it came to that.
One in particular caught my attention. Florida Democratic representative Jared Moskowitz said:

(If) Marjorie Taylor Greene, someone who wants states to secede from the union, brings up a motion to vacate, I will not support her doing that under any circumstance. Democrats don't even let her rename post offices. I'm not going to let her make a motion to vacate.

Question: Why don't Democrats let Representative Greene rename post offices, and how do they prevent her from doing so?

The post office thing is probalby just generic ref to https://www.theatlantic.com/politics/archive/2015/04/the-crackdown-on-naming-post-offices/452544/ etc.

I don't think she ever introduced a postal office naming bill, but she did introduce a bill to name some other Federal building, which did pass the House (HR 532)

I'm curious how you already know what people will say tomorrow on CNN. or is the 19 a typo?

@Nzall Occam's razor suggests it's a typo; 19 is definitely wrong. But interestingly enough I did post the question  on the 17th at 22:46 UTC (the "z" stands for "zulu time") after I viewed the video, but the YouTube page shows 18th (without a time stamp) even thought the US lags behind UTC. So now I don't know what to believe! Anyway I'll change the 19 to 18 to reflect what the web page says.

This is just a rhetorical device, not a reference to any actual attempt to rename post offices. They're saying that she's such a whack-job that they won't even support her on inconsequential matters, and they certainly won't support her on important matters like ousting the Speaker of the House.
It's like what you say "I wouldn't touch that with a ten-foot pole." You're not saying you actually have such a pole.
If she did try to rename a post office, they'd probably be concerned that she'd propose naming it after a Confederate hero, in opposition to the recent trend of removing things (statues, official building names, etc.) that honor these people. But that's not what they're actually talking about.

Naming a post office requires unanimity from the state's congressional members to move it to the floor for a vote. So all it takes is a single member from Georgia to prevent that.
In a way this requires her to get more support from democratic members from her state then a motion to vacate the speaker position.
Naming Post Offices Through Legislation

Unanimity of a state’s congressional delegation is required for the movement of naming bills to the floor of the House or Senate. Additionally, the Senate committee of jurisdiction has adopted the rule that it “will not consider any legislation that would name a postal facility for a living person with the exception of bills naming facilities after former Presidents and Vice Presidents of the United States, former Members of Congress over 70 years of age, former state or local elected officials over 70 years of age, former judges over 70 years of age, or wounded veterans.”


Ironically enough, naming a post office is one of the four bills MTG has actually gotten through Congress! Now, she was not the sole sponsor (or even the introductory sponsor), and since the purpose of the bill was to name a PO in GA after civil rights leader John Lewis, Democrats all voted in favor of the bill. It was always going to pass, as it had 364 cosponsors, but Rep. Greene doesn't have many other bills to show for herself, so I guess this one stands out on her 4 for 213 record.
Obviously, as other answers point out, this was just a rhetorical device, though perhaps an unfortunately inaccurate one. If we instead take the quote to mean that Democrats would not allow MTG to introduce a bill renaming a PO, that would be very reasonable.

Concice and definitive; thanks!

Presumably MTG didn't rename the Post Office in this instance, in the sense that she didn't choose the new name for it.
